# No maximise/minimise/close buttons on a new window

Tags: window-manager

When I opened a new window(not maximised) I used to close with the left-top buttons, now they don't exist anymore. To close it I must drag it or maximise it... where the hell did the buttons go!?

A image of the issue:
[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and do the buttons appear if you move the mouse into the top left of the screen (where you would expect to find them)?

Answer (score 0):

I have had some issues with Compiz and older libs from application causing this issue, I would open terminal and type **metacity - -replace &** to get my borders back

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt
```

If the problem persists try this:

Install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open it searching in the Dash for "ccsm", go to Effects category and enable Window Decoration. Restart your system and you should get the buttons back. If it do not work just leave a comment.

Comment: The problem is not the window borders, if you take a look at the screenshow you will notice there're not the maximise/minimise/close buttons at the top-left corner.

Just a note: the mouse is on the top-left corner but the screenshots make the cursor non-visible.

Comment: The problem isn't the window borders? In the image I can't see any window border in the window, the buttons aren't supposed to appear on the top-left corner when the window isn't maximized, it is to appear on the window titlebar. Like this: http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/5491/captura1e.png The close/maximize/minimize buttons will only appear on the top-left corner when the window is maximized: http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/3369/captura2s.png